# PostgreSQL Exception: “An I/O error occured while sending to the backend”

Tags: postgresql, grails

I run two web app in a machine and one DB in another machine.(They use the same DB)
One can run very well,But another one always down after about 4 hours.

Here is error information:

```
Error 2014-11-03 13:31:05,902 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - An I/O error occured while sending to the backend.
| Error 2014-11-03 13:31:05,904 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - This connection has been closed.
```

Postgresql logs:

```
2014-10-26 23:41:31 CDT WARNING:  pgstat wait timeout
2014-10-27 01:13:48 CDT WARNING:  pgstat wait timeout
2014-10-27 03:55:46 CDT LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection timed out
2014-10-27 03:55:46 CDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
```

Who caused this problem, app or database? or net?

Comment: Network connection, most likely NAT connection tracking table expiry.

Answer (score 2):

Reason:

At this point it was clear that the TCP connection that was sitting idle was already broken, but our app still assumed it to be open. By idle connections, I mean connections in the pool that aren’t in active use at the moment by the application.

After some search, I came to the conclusion that the network firewall between my app and the database is dropping the idle/stale connections after 1 hour. It seemed to be a common problem that many people have faced.

Solution:

In grails, you can set this in DataSource.groovy.

```
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            //configure DBCP 
            properties {
                maxActive = 50
                maxIdle = 25
                minIdle = 1
                initialSize = 1
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
                numTestsPerEvictionRun = 3
                maxWait = 10000

                testOnBorrow = true
                testWhileIdle = true
                testOnReturn = false

                validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```